# find a string in a column and replace it with upper value

Tags: excel

I am working on an excel sheet.I need to find a value in column and then replace it from all above column value(comma seperated), where the string ocured last time.
Here is an image of what i need(col 2).

```
col1    col2
12      12
34      34
45      45
65      65
FALSE   12,34,45,65
78      78
97      97
36      36
8       8
76      76
98      98
FALSE   78,97,36,8,76,98
6       6
980     980
3467    3467
FALSE   6,98,03,467
```

I don't know how to upload excel file so pasting data from excel.Please help me.

Comment: your question seems to be unrelated with its title. Be more specific & show us code you've tried and where is your error message

Answer (score 0):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub FillCol()
    Dim col1 As String, col2 As String, msg As String, _
        i As Long, N As Long
    col1 = "A"
    col2 = "B"
    msg = ""
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, col1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        If Cells(i, col1).Value = "False" Then
            Cells(i, col2).Value = Left(msg, Len(msg) - 1)
            msg = ""
        Else
        Cells(i, col2).Value = Cells(i, col1).Value
        msg = msg & Cells(i, col1).Value & ","
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It has been coded for columns **A** & **B**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use formulas, there is a 2-column solution that should work.

For this, col1 = Column A, col2= Column B.  Column A has your original data.  Column B will end up with your desired results.  Column C 'builds' the string that you want to use in Column B whenever there is a 'FALSE' value in column A.

In cell B1, use this formula:

```
=IF(A1=FALSE,"",A1)
```

In cell B2, use this formula, then copy & paste to the bottom:

```
=IF(A2=FALSE,IF(LEFT(C1,2)=" ,",SUBSTITUTE(C1," ,","",1),C1),A2)
```

In cell C1, use this formula:

```
=IF(A1=FALSE,"",A1)
```

In cell C2, use this formula, then copy & paste to the bottom:

```
=IF(A2=FALSE,"",C1&" ,"&A2)
```

This should give you the desired results in Column B.